# Not able to insert "index":"not_analyzed" in mapping of elasticsearch 6.1.2

Tags: java, elasticsearch, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, elasticsearch-6

I am trying to find a match a name with case sensitive. When I tried below code it worked as expected for case insensitive.

```
        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data.put("GroupId", "3");
        data.put("GroupName", "testGroup three");
        data.put("CreatedDateTime", "20180115130026757+0000");
        data.put("UpdatedDateTime", "20180115130026757+0000");
        data.put("Createdby", "3");
        data.put("GroupUser",  "{1,2,3,4}");
        data.put("status", "active");

        String mapping = {"typename":{"properties":{
        "GroupName":{"type":"text","index":"not_analyzed"},
        "Createdby":{"type":"text","index":"not_analyzed"},
        "GroupUser":{"type":"text","index":"not_analyzed"},
        "UpdatedDateTime":{"type":"text","index":"not_analyzed"},
        "CreatedDateTime":{"type":"text","index":"not_analyzed"},
        "GroupId":{"type":"text","index":"not_analyzed"},
        "status":{"type":"text","index":"not_analyzed"}}}}

        client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddresses(new TransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress(ipaddress, port)));

        //inserting record
        IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex(indexName, typeName).setSource(data).get();

        //inserting mapping
        client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping(indexName)
        .setType("typeName")
        .setSource(mapping, XContentType.JSON)
        .get();
```

To find the case sensitive value, I found that to use the index as not_analyzed. I tried the following

```
        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data.put("GroupId", "3");
        data.put("GroupName", "testGroup three");
        data.put("CreatedDateTime", "20180115130026757+0000");
        data.put("UpdatedDateTime", "20180115130026757+0000");
        data.put("Createdby", "3");
        data.put("GroupUser",  "{1,2,3,4}");
        data.put("status", "active");

        String mapping = {"typename":{"properties":{
        "GroupName":{"type":"text","index":"not_analyzed"},
        "Createdby":{"type":"text","index":"not_analyzed"},
        "GroupUser":{"type":"text","index":"not_analyzed"},
        "UpdatedDateTime":{"type":"text","index":"not_analyzed"},
        "CreatedDateTime":{"type":"text","index":"not_analyzed"},
        "GroupId":{"type":"text","index":"not_analyzed"},
        "status":{"type":"text","index":"not_analyzed"}}}}

        client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddresses(new TransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress(ipaddress, port)));

        //inserting record
        IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex(indexName, typeName).setSource(data).get();

        //inserting mapping
        client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping(indexName)
        .setType("typeName")
        .setSource(mapping, XContentType.JSON)
        .get();
```

I am getting an exception as shown below

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not convert [GroupName.index] to boolean
```

I want to accomplish to two scenarios below:

```
 1. Find by case sensitive
 2. Find by case insensitive.
```

Elastic search version is 6.1.2.

Any help is really appreciated.

**UPDATE-1**

As per @Val, I have changed the code to:

```
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    data.put("GroupId", "3");
    data.put("GroupName", "testGroup three");
    data.put("CreatedDateTime", "20180115130026757+0000");
    data.put("UpdatedDateTime", "20180115130026757+0000");
    data.put("Createdby", "3");
    data.put("GroupUser",  "{1,2,3,4}");
    data.put("status", "active");

    String mapping = {"typename":{"properties":{
    "GroupName":{"type":"keyword"},
    "Createdby":{"type":"keyword"},
    "GroupUser":{"type":"keyword"},
    "UpdatedDateTime":{"keyword":"text"},
    "CreatedDateTime":{"keyword":"text"},
    "GroupId":{"type":"keyword"},
    "status":{"type":"keyword"}}}}

    client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddresses(new TransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress(ipaddress, port)));

   client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("indexName").get(); 

    //inserting mapping
    client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping(indexName)
    .setType("typeName")
    .setSource(mapping, XContentType.JSON)
    .get();

    //inserting record
    IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex(indexName, typeName).setSource(data).get();
```

Now I am able to insert. But when I search for the a value in GroupName, the result is empty.

Comment: Also can you update your question with whatever you have in the `data` variable?

Comment: @Val I have updated my question for data variable.

Comment: Ok, then try my answer below, but make sure to delete your index first :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`not_analyzed` is deprecated, you need to use `keyword` instead.

Try this mapping below, instead:

```
String mapping = {
  "typename": {
    "properties": {
      "GroupName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "Createdby": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "GroupUser": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "UpdatedDateTime": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSZ"
      },
      "CreatedDateTime": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSZ"
      },
      "GroupId": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "status": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also make sure to put the mapping before inserting the data, i.e.

execute:

```
//inserting mapping
```

before:

```
//inserting record
```

Comment: Please check my updated question. When I tried type as keyword. I see different error saying `mapper [CreatedDateTime] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [keyword]`

Comment: make sure to delete your index first

Comment: I did, its the same

Comment: The mapping for your date fields is not correct. See my updated answer

Comment: If I do mapping before indexing, I am getting `no such index` error.

Comment: Call `client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("indexName").get();` before `putMapping`. Or you can do it in one shot [like this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-admin-indices.html#java-admin-indices-put-mapping)

Comment: Insertion is successful, but when I search work in groupname, it is not returning the values. For a groupname for example Groupname is "General Group" and when I search for "General" it returned as 0 for match query.

Comment: That's a big step forward. now show your query please

Comment: {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "match" : {
          "GroupName" : {
            "query" : "General"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  }
}

Comment: Since you want exact search you must search for `General Group` (with the same casing) otherwise it won't work, that's the whole purpose of the `keyword` type, the value is not analyzed at all (i.e. not tokenized, not lowercase, etc).

Comment: but our requirement is to find both 1. Find by case sensitive
 2. Find by case insensitive. along with full match and partial match of values

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question. Then the mapping is a bit different, see my updated answer. You can then run case-insensitive searches on the `GroupName` field and case-sensitive searches on the `GroupName.keyword` field.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to check an index exist before creating the index using rest high client in presently I had using elasticsearch 6.1.3

Comment: For those interested, the new question/answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927002/how-to-find-index-exists-in-elasticsearch-6-2-1/48927070#48927070