# How to find index exists in elasticsearch 6.2.1?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, indexing

I had trying to check whether a index exists in the RestHighLevelClient of elasticsearch 6.2.1

presently I am using using following code

```
    try {

        OpenIndexRequest openIndexRequest = new OpenIndexRequest(indexName);
        client.indices().open(openIndexRequest, header).isAcknowledged();

    } catch (ElasticsearchStatusException ex) {
        String m = "Elasticsearch exception [type=index_not_found_exception, reason=no such index]";

        if (m.equals(ex.getMessage())) {
            //TODO In case index does not exists
        }
    }
```

it works fine but I want to find some relevant methods like

```
client.indices().exists(indexname);
```

elastic search 6.2.1

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until this is supported by the high-level REST client (probably as of 6.3), you can achieve this by using the low-level REST client and issuing a [HEAD HTTP request to your index name](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-exists.html)

```
Response response = restClient.performRequest("HEAD", "/" + indexname); 
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); 
if (statusCode == 404) {
   // index does not exist
} else {
   // index exists
}
```

Comment: Can you help for this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921481/how-to-search-starting-and-ending-of-a-sentence-in-elasticsearch

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921481/how-to-search-starting-and-ending-of-a-sentence-in-elasticsearch?noredirect=1&lq=1 Can you answer this one to @Val

Comment: Just added a comment